# Java Regex Forward Slash Causing Match Not To Be Made

Tags: java, regex

We are trying to make a match on any text between a triplet of "s for example

""" Some text here """

We want to capture Some text here. This we have working alright, however, we have an issue when the text between the triplet of "s contains a forward slash `/`. So for example """ This doesn/'t work """, so if we have have;

""" This doesn/'t work """
""" Some text here """

Then the match goes and ignores the first """ and goes on to match up to the second closing """ so the match becomes;

This doesn/'t work Some text here

When all we want is This doesn/'t work. The regex I am using is as follows;

```
(?:"{3})([\p{Alnum}|\p{Punct}|\p{Space}]*)(?:"{3})
```

We are using capturing groups as a note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like problem with greedy/lazy quantifier. Change `*` to `*?` for lazy matching.

i.e. `(?:"{3})([\p{ALnum}|\p{Punct}|\p{Space}]*?)(?:"{3})`

Comment: This worked a treat. Would you have a link to a resource you can recommend on lazy matching / greedy/lazy quantifiers? Thank you.

Comment: In the first instance (albeit half-way down) [RegularExpressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), and in depth [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/).

Answer (score 0):

This gives desired result (tested in rubular.com):

Regex: `"""\s*([\S]+)\s+([\S]+)\s+([\S]+)\s*"""`
Input: `""" This doesn/'t work """ """ Some text here """`
Match: `""" This doesn/'t work """`,  `""" Some text here """`

Match groups:

```
Match 1
1.  This
2.  doesn/'t
3.  work
Match 2
1.  Some
2.  text
3.  here
```

Comment: Don't think this is what the OP wants, since it is asserting 3 non-space sequences.

Comment: Ah, you mean they don't want to match the other match group if the "/" appears?

Comment: This is correct, I only ever want to match the text between the first set of """.

Comment: Can't you simply ignore other match groups then?

Comment: I do ignore them, using (?:) to define them as groups rather than capturing groups.